# Get Commentary from Posts with no MentionElement

Tags: linkedin-api

I am getting the posts from linkedin but on the response I'm getting the commentary with all the supported elements(TextElement, MentionElement,HastagTemplate).

Can we do some filters on the request in order to only get plain text ?

This is my api endpoint

**https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A2127&isDsc=false&q=author&count=100**

This is the response I'm getting nowadays

Congratulations to @[Becca Meinz] (urn:li:person:6sc1MHJfcE), Vice President of Best Buy's End-to-End Supply Chain Strategy, for her inclusion on @[Business Insider] (urn:li:organization:683279)'s 100 People Transforming Business list. https://bby.me/wj29an